# python spyder conda install failure

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder, conda

I am new to Python, now I am using Anaconda Spyder as my main Python distribution. I am learning how to use conda to install/update packages. When I read relevant books and searched online, it seemed that All I need to do is to type "conda install " or type "conda update ". When I typed so in my spyder console, I found error message as follows. Where am I wrong here? Thanks for help.

[image]

Someone suggested me to run it in cmd not in Spyder. Here is my output when I run it in cmd. The update of my pandas also fails in cmd line. 
[image]

Answer (score 9):

You are trying to use a Python console to update your conda distribution when you have to update it from your local console.

I guess you're using Windows, just open the command prompt (cmd.exe), and from there update the conda distribution with the commands you already know:

```
conda update conda
conda update anaconda
conda install <package>
```

**Update:**

Conda commands have to be used directly in the command prompt:

[image]

Comment: I am still a little confused here. The picture I attached is the code I run in Anaconda Spyder. Do you mean that I need to type "conda update anaconda" in my command prompt? I did so, and there still shows that invalid syntax. I will appreciate it if you can give me more detailed hints, such as print screen pictures. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do not open a python shell, **type your conda commands directly in your command prompt**. Simply `C:\>conda update pandas`, don't type `python` first. Check the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I started exploring Python on Spyder(Anaconda) and faced these issues. Though late, but this could help someone facing similar issues. I performed these on Windows7 and Anaconda3(64bit).

**Step1**: Identify the location where you installed your Anaconda.

```
Windows > All Programs > Anaconda3(64 bit) > Right Click on Spyder > Properties.
It shows Spyder target location, say, "C:\bla\bla\anaconda3\Scripts\spyder-script.py"
```

**Step2**: Now through folder explorer navigate to identified path as in Step1 i.e. "C:\bla\bla\anaconda3\Scripts\"

```
Here you will see many exe files including conda.exe and pip.exe
```

**Step3**: Open Windows Command prompt

```
C:\>cd C:\bla\bla\anaconda3\Scripts
C:\bla\bla\anaconda3\Scripts>
```

**Step4**: Now simply type all your pip or conda commands. It will install these libraries

```
C:\bla\bla\anaconda3\Scripts>pip install pandas
C:\bla\bla\anaconda3\Scripts>conda update conda
```

**Step5**: Now you can import the installed libraries directly in Spyder. It won't complain.